# VFS priority services for EEA family permit applicants

Tags: visas, uk, eu-citizens, family, freedom-of-movement

There's an EEA national in the USA who wants to take a holiday in the UK with his visa-national spouse (Cambodian). He wants to benefit from [EU Directive 2004/38/EC](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2004:158:0077:0123:en:PDF) so that they can get an [EEA family permit issued by the UK](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/overview).

The permit itself is free, but their holiday has a short fuse on it. They want to use the so-called [Gold Premium Service Package](http://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/usa/user_pay_services.html#3) and book a short-term notice appointment in Miami. They are ready and willing to pay, but [the site](http://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/usa/user_pay_services.html) seems to indicate that this service is not available for family permit applicants.  Is it a misprint?

How can an EEA national use priority services at a Visa Facilitation Centre? I can see [from here](https://www.gov.uk/ukvi-premium-service-centres/when-you-cant-use-the-service) that EEA nationals wanting a permanent residence card or a registration certificate are excluded. It does not mention the family permit and it does not explain how to accelerate an application in the first instance (which is the issue at hand).

Comment: Your "from here" link points into a guide that concerns in-country applications only, which explains why it mentions residence cards but not family permits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your "the site" link, it appears that family permit applications cannot receive any more priority than they already have because of the directive and/or regulations:

> EEA Family Permit applicants are not required to purchase priority services. EEA Family Permit applications are considered priority, free of any additional charge.